# Dropdownlist in C# & ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, list, asp.net-core, select, dropdown

I want to create a dropdown with C#, ASP.NET Core that will be displayed in the view and get the information of the dropdown list from the database and display it in the view. How can I do this?

While the `selectListItem` in the space there is a name that is obsolete.

```
public class AddUserRoleDto
{
   public string Id { get; set; }
   public string Role { get; set; }
   public List<SelectListItem> Roles{ get; set; }
}

public IActionResult AddUserRole(string Id)
{
   var role = new List<SelectListItem>(
        _roleManager.Roles.Select(p => new SelectListItem
                     {
                         Text = p.Name,
                         Value = p.Name
                     }).ToList());
  


   return View(new AddUserRoleDto
                   {
                       Id = Id,
                       Roles = role,
                   });
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by SelectListItem in the space?

Comment: I don't see `SelectListItem` as being marked obsolete ..... where are you getting it from? Check [the official MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.selectlistitem?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to create a dropdown with C#, ASP.NET Core that will be
> displayed in the view

In the AddUserRole, you can use ViewBag to pass the SelectList to the view:

```
public IActionResult AddUserRole(string Id)
{
     //do your staff
     ViewBag.Roles = new SelectList(_roleManager.Roles, "Name", "Name");
}
```

Then in the view use asp-items :

```
<select name="Roles" class="form-control" asp-items="@ViewBag.Roles"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Model:

```cs
public class AddUserRoleDto: IdentityUser
{
    public string? RoleId { get; set; }
    public string? Role { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem>? RoleList { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult AddUserRole(string userId)
{
    var user = _db.AppUser.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == userId);
    if (user == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    var userRole = _db.UserRoles.ToList();
    var roles = _db.Roles.ToList();
    var role = userRole.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserId == user.Id);
    if (role != null)
    {
        user.RoleId = roles.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == role.RoleId).Id;
    }
    user.RoleList = _db.Roles.Select(u => new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = u.Name,
        Value = u.Id
    });
    return View(user);
}
```

Comment: My question is the namespace that selectListItem
It is obsolete. What can I do?

Comment: I have updated the code :) Tailor it according to to your needs.